# Flipping Last, First to First Last while generating email from table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, null

The code below works well to give me everything after the comma, but breaks when a cell is null. I am using this to grab first names from a list, and generate an email with them.

```
Function GetFirstName(ByVal Str As String) As String
Dim arrStr
arrStr = Split(Str, ",")
GetFirstName = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))
End Function
```

I have been trying to add a null statement, but have failed each time. Thanks for your help!

(BONUS: I get the middle initial as well sometimes, as it comes after the comma. any way I can stop it after the first word?)

Comment: Try `If UBound(arrStr) > -1 Then GetFirstName = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))`

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
Function GetFirstName(ByVal Str As String) As String
    Dim arrStr As Variant
    arrStr = Split(Str, ",")
    If UBound(arrStr) > -1 Then
        'Trim to remove any leading/trailing spaces.
        GetFirstName = Trim(arrStr(UBound(arrStr)))

        Dim MidName As Long
        MidName = InStrRev(GetFirstName, " ")
        If MidName > 0 Then GetFirstName = Left(GetFirstName, MidName - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: its close! thank you so much. The code works if there is a null, but pulls the middle initial instead of the first name ie: Johnson, Robert D comes in as D.

Comment: My mistake - when you said the middle initial comes after the comma I was thinking _<First Name>, <Middle Initial> <Surname>_.  I'll update the answer.